# Maven pom.xml not reading System environment variables

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My environment :
JDK17
Maven 3.6
Eclipse 2022-06

In my parent pom.xml , I have put a property as below:

```
<properties>
<LOCAL_REPOSITORY>${env.LOCAL_REPOSITORY}</LOCAL_REPOSITORY>
</properties>
```

and added a LOCAL_REPOSITORY variable in system environment as well. LOCAL_REPOSITORY points to my

```
C:\Users\userName\.m2\repository
```

In child pom.xml, I used echo task as :

```
<echo message="LOCAL_REPOSITORY"/>
<echo message="${LOCAL_REPOSITORY}"/>
<echo message="${env.LOCAL_REPOSITORY}"/>
```

But all I get in output is :

```
LOCAL_REPOSITORY
${env.LOCAL_REPOSITORY}
${env.LOCAL_REPOSITORY}
```

While I was able to add a LOCAL_REPOSITORY as variable in Eclipse classpath variables, seems I can use it only as kind="var" in .classpath files. If that can be used by passing a $ or something , that'd be swell.

Awaiting a good suggestion.

Comment: The location for your local repository is defined in `settings.xml` which is located in `$HOME/.m2/` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I found it. Seems I had changes my home directory somewhere else and it was pointing there. Yet I was able to solve this thru  usage of a .bat file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @khmarbaise , I had placed settings.xml elsewhere because my home dir was also set somewhere else.

I however solved it thru creating a .bat file on windows (location: project/random_folder_name_of_your_choice/envMaven.bat) Just place this entry there:

`set LOCAL_REPOSITORY=C:/Users/userName/.m2/repository`.

I would still give @khmarbaise 's suggestion a try first up tho.